# Dynamical serialization with Django REST

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a `Person` model, and `Address` model. One `person` can have multiple addresses, so the `Address` model looks like:

```
Address(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="addresses")
    ...
```

I want to serialize a `person` instance, and I do the simplest thing:

```
PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (..., "addresses", ...)
```

**However, suppose I want to serialize `addresses` based on the current `request.user`, so that different current `user`s view different set of addresses, how should I modify the code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this for a Detail View, you should implement a serializer for Address model, too. See [this example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example) for nested serializer relationships. Also, in your api view you must make a query according to request.user.

If you are doing this for a List View, PersonSerializer should have a SerializerMethodField. With this, user will be able to see his own addresses and will not be able to see others' addresses.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    addresses = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_addresses')

    class Meta:
        fields = (..., "addresses", ...)

    def get_addresses(self, obj):
        if obj.pk != self.context['request'].user.pk:
            return ""
        else:
            return obj.addresses
```

P.S: I assume your custom user model is Person since you didn't supply much information.

Comment: Keep in mind that a serializer should by design also work outside a request/response cycle. It does not always have a request object available.

Comment: Perfect, `SerializerMethodField` is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want an static endpoint like /user/current/ which gives you the current request user's Person object + associated address records. Add a view like this:

```
class CurrentUser(GenericAPIView):
    model = Person
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        return Response(self.get_serializer(request.user).data)
```

It's only accessible if the user is not anonymous and will use your PersonSerializer to dump out the request user. The associated address records come along as you wish if you set up your 'addresses' serializer field accordingly, as described here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships